# Generic Repository in DB first Entity Framework Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I am writing a generic repository as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  . I am using DB First approach to generate EF model.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal SchoolContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    //Removed for brevity reason
}
```

In my case intellisense is not showing Set as function, rather it lists all the entities. To make it generic I would not need named entities but the generic method.

**How to assign it to generic entities or if there is any other better way to write generic repository?**

Comment: If `SchoolContext` derives from `DbContext`, it should have the `Set()` method. Does your current code compile?

Comment: I have a feeling you are going in a wrong direction. Generic repo that wraps context and db set does not make sense at all.

Comment: @haim770 it in fact does derive from DBContext.

Comment: @niksofteng It will be good if you could give explanatory answer? I have hundreds of entities and writing 100 IRepository is time consuming while most of them are going to do same type of jobs.

Comment: Do you get the `Set()` function when you change the type of your context in the repository from `SchoolContext` to `DbContext`?

Comment: @satishsuthar *It will be good if you could give explanatory answer?* - That wont fit in comment and will not be a valid answer for this question. So I suggest you open up new question just for that. In fact post it on `codereview` site, not SO. Search Google/SO before doing so because there're hundreds of articles explaining why it is useless to have Repository pattern over EF.

Answer (score 0):

I was separating Repository layer into a different class library project to add proper N-Tier layering in to my code stack and the new project didn't have a reference to EnityFramework. After adding a refrence to EnityFramework it worked!

I don't know if that's a good design because it's very tightly coupling my repository with Entity Framework and I'll have to mock DataContext and DBSet while unit testing.

Is there a better approach to what I am doing or is this ok?